# Algebraic relations between Schur functors

Tags: rt.representation-theory

I am afraid questions might be trivial and well-known, well, nevervethless. I'll ask it.

Consider category of vector spaces.
There are naturally defined functors to itself : take vector space and consider its symmetric or antisymmetric powers, more general things can be constructed - which is called Schur functors (as far as I understand) they are indexed by Young diagrams.
(They are defined as certain subspaces in tensor product $V^{\otimes n}$, for example if we take $V^{\otimes 3}$ then there are symmetric tensors, antisymmetric and there is certain complement to them - that is one of the Schur functors).

So we get many functors $F_{diagr}$.
Functors can be composed.
Are there any relations between composition of functors ? E.g. $F_{d1} F_{d2} = F_{d3} F_{d4}$ or whatever ?

Also functors on the catetory of vectors spaces can be added - so we have some algebra.
What are the relations in this algebra ?

Comment: You are asking about plethysms.

Comment: Wilberd van der Kellen's is right, but there might be some more to say here. The perspective in the plethysm literature is usually to write a composition of two Schur functors as a linear combination of other Schur functors -- like describing a ring by giving a multiplication table for basis elements. It might be interesting to think about describing this ring by generators and relations instead.

Comment: Some plethysym relations in special cases are known, and every few years a new paper comes out with another special case.  This is known to be a hard problem in general.
