# Categorification and Schur functors 

Tags: rt.representation-theory

Are Schur functors and categorification somehow related ?

If yes, probably looking on Schur functors (which I know) one can illustrate on this example  why "categorification" (which I do not know) is so important/popular now ? 
(I am intersted to learn somehting about "categorification", but I would prefer to have
some "good entering point", meaning to relate it to what I know).

Schur functors - are some functors from category of vector spaces to itself.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_functor
For example take vector space and send it to $S^n(V)$ n-th symmetric power (can be antisymmetric).

"Categorification" - briefly looking at MO discussions about it and abstracts of some papers, I got an impression that it is about realizing certain algebras as functors of some categories.
For example abstact of Khovanov's lectures  http://arxiv.org/abs/1008.5084 contains the
following sentence " diagrammatic categorification of positive halves of quantum groups".
 Is my understanding  correct ?

PS

[What precisely Is "Categorification"?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/4841/what-precisely-is-categorification)

[Algebraic relations between Schur functors](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/89001/algebraic-relations-between-schur-functors)

Comment: The nlab article on Schur functors is highly recommended http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Schur+functor. The message is that the category of Schur functors is just End(U), where U is the forgetful functor from cocomplete (or at least Cauchy-complete) tensor categories to categories.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Categorification can be thought of as the process of replacing equalities with isomorphisms (in some category). A basic example is replacing a numerical combinatorial identity such as
$$2^n = \sum_{k=0}^n {n \choose k}$$

with a bijection between two sets (an isomorphism in $\text{Set}$); in this case, between the set of subsets of $\{ 1, 2, ... n \}$ and the disjoint union of the sets of subsets of size $k$ over all $k$.

As another example, the category $\text{FinSet}$ of finite sets itself categorifies the rng $\mathbb{N}_{\ge 0}$ of non-negative integers; the coproduct categorifies addition and the product categorifies multiplication. (Also taking Hom-sets categorifies exponentiation.) In this way we replace equalities such as $1 + 1 = 2$ with isomorphisms $1 \sqcup 1 \cong 2$ (where $1$ is the set with one element, $2$ is the set with two elements, and $\sqcup$ is the coproduct).

Schur functors categorify the theory of symmetric functions (specifically of [Schur functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_polynomial)). Taking the direct sum of Schur functors categorifies addition of symmetric functions, taking the tensor product categorifies multiplication of symmetric functions, and composing categorifies [plethysm](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/plethysm). So here we replace equalities between expressions involving symmetric functions with natural isomorphisms between expressions involving Schur functors.

---

As far as the linked arXiv paper goes, the idea is to replace a ring $A$ by a category $C$ with direct sums and tensor products such that the latter distributes over the former, such as the category of $(R, R)$-bimodules for some ring $R$. Equality of elements in $A$ is then replaced by isomorphism between objects in $C$. Taking the Grothendieck group of $C$ (a form of decategorification) should then recover the original ring.

One reason to attempt to do this is that the category $C$ may have a distinguished set of objects that provides a distinguished set of generators for $A$. For example, the Hecke algebra $H_n$ of $S_n$ turns out to be the Grothendieck group of the category of [Soergel bimodules](http://sbseminar.wordpress.com/2007/07/23/soergel-bimodules/). Among these we can distinguish the indecomposable modules, and these turn out to give the Kazhdan-Lusztig basis of $H_n$.

Comment: @Qiauchu Yuan Thank You for the answer ! What do you mean by "composing" symmetric functions ?  

Comment: Added phrase: "For example abstact of Khovanov's lectures  http://arxiv.org/abs/1008.5084 contains the
following senteces " diagrammatic categorification of positive halves of quantum groups"." Can you comment on it ? It does not seems like "identities" categorification.


Comment: @Alexander: Schur functors are the things that can be composed. Decategorifying this construction gives rise to plethysm of symmetric functions. 

Comment: @Alexander: it is. See Proposition 2 on p. 23. 

Comment: @Qiauchu Can plethysm be described solely in terms of symmetric functions and what does it mean from this point of view ? 

Comment: @Alexander: yes, if I'm not mistaken. To go from Schur functors to symmetric functions you consider the action of the Schur functor on a diagonal endomorphism of a vector space $V$ of dimension $n$ with variable diagonal entries $x_1, ... x_n$; the trace corresponding endomorphism of $S^{\lambda}(V)$ is the corresponding symmetric function (in $n$ variables, and then we can let $n \to \infty$). From this perspective, plethysm of symmetric functions corresponds to substituting the monomials that make up one symmetric function into another symmetric function. 

Comment: @Qiauchu Thank You ! However it sounds a little bit non-invariantly and not so obvious to understand, is it important that functions are symmetric and number of variables is infinite ? Or we can compose any 2 two functions e.g. f= x+2y g= x^2+3z ? 

Comment: @Alexander: that the functions are symmetric ensures that it doesn't matter what order we substitute the monomials in. The number of variables doesn't seem like a big deal to me, but if you want to use a finite number of variables then that finite number is different in general for the two symmetric functions you're plethying (that's probably not a word but I can't think of a better way to say it). 

Comment: @Qiauchu Thank You ! Still what exactly means  "substituting the monomials that make up one symmetric function into another symmetric function" ? E.g. consider f= x1+x2 + ... g=f what will be f subs f ? 

Comment: @Alexander: it's just $f = e_1$ again. Note that the corresponding Schur functor is the identity functor. A better example is to take $e_2 = x_1 x_2 + x_2 x_3 + x_3 x_1$ (I'll restrict to $3$ variables for simplicity) so that $e_2 \circ e_2 = (x_1 x_2)(x_2 x_3) + (x_2 x_3)(x_3 x_1) + (x_3 x_1)(x_1 x_2)$. 